# C++ wxWidgets - trouble with ScrolledWindow that has no width

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm very new to wxWidgets, and C++, but I'm familiar with other toolkits. I wanted a layout like this:

[image: My design]

and this is what it looks like. It looks as though my window has no width at all:

[image]

So this is my code, heavily annotated.

And here's my code, which I believe is as close to intent as I can get it.
The design is this, each "sender", "sent at" and "message" is in a unique block based on a reusable panel:

```
//CONTENTS OF GUI_MESSAGE_ITEM.H

#ifndef GUIMESSAGEITEM_H
#define GUIMESSAGEITEM_H

#include "wx/panel.h" // Base class: wxPanel
#include "wx/stattext.h"
#include "sms_message.h"
#include "wx/window.h"
#include "wx/wx.h"

class GUIMessageItem : public wxPanel {

public:
    GUIMessageItem(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID winid, const SMSMessage& smsMessage);
    ~GUIMessageItem();

private:
    wxStaticText* stSender;
    wxStaticText* stSentTime;
    wxStaticText* stMessageContents;
};

#endif // GUIMESSAGEITEM_H

//CONTENTS OF GUI_MESSAGE_ITEM.CPP

#include "gui_message_item.h"

GUIMessageItem::GUIMessageItem(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID winid, const SMSMessage& smsMessage) :
    wxPanel(parent, winid),
    stSender(new wxStaticText(this, winid, smsMessage.GetSender())),
    stSentTime(new wxStaticText(this, winid, smsMessage.GetSentTime())),
    stMessageContents(new wxStaticText(this, winid, smsMessage.GetMessage()))
{
    wxColour blue(wxT("#2A2AF7"));
    wxColour green(wxT("#56DB4F"));
    wxFont originalFont = stSender->GetFont();
    wxFont boldFont(originalFont);
    boldFont.SetWeight( wxFONTWEIGHT_BOLD );
    wxSize stsMin(100, 60);
    wxSize bodyMin(300, 100);

    stSender->SetForegroundColour(blue);
    stSentTime->SetForegroundColour(green);
    stSender->SetFont(boldFont);
    stSentTime->SetFont(boldFont);
    stSender->SetMinSize(stsMin);
    stSentTime->SetMinSize(stsMin);

    stMessageContents->SetMinSize(bodyMin);
    stMessageContents->Wrap(200);

    wxBoxSizer* lines = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );
    wxBoxSizer* topLine = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );
    lines->AddSpacer(4);
    topLine->AddSpacer(5);
    this->SetSizer(lines);

    topLine->Add(stSender, wxALIGN_LEFT);
    topLine->Add(stSentTime, wxALIGN_RIGHT);
    lines->Add(topLine);
    lines->Add(stMessageContents, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL );

    lines->SetMinSize(wxSize(400,400));
    this->FitInside();
    this->Layout();
}

GUIMessageItem::~GUIMessageItem()
{
}

//MAIN CODE FOR THE WHOLE FORM

MainFrameBase::MainFrameBase( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxFrame( parent, id, title, pos, size, style )
{
    this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );

    //Menu Bar stuff.
    m_menuBar = new wxMenuBar( 0 );
    m_menuFile = new wxMenu();
    wxMenuItem* menuFileExit;
    menuFileExit = new wxMenuItem( m_menuFile, wxID_EXIT, wxString( _("E&xit") ) + wxT('\t') + wxT("Alt+X"), wxEmptyString, wxITEM_NORMAL );

    wxMenuItem* menuFileOpen;
    menuFileOpen = new wxMenuItem( m_menuFile, wxID_OPEN, wxString( _("&Open") ) + wxT('\t') + wxT("Alt+O"), wxEmptyString, wxITEM_NORMAL );

    m_menuFile->Append( menuFileOpen );
    m_menuFile->Append( menuFileExit );
    m_menuBar->Append( m_menuFile, _("&File") );

    this->SetMenuBar( m_menuBar );

    //main sizer for whole interface
    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

    this->SetSizer( mainSizer );

    // Filter box section
    wxStaticText* filterLabel = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Filter by Sender:"));

    m_filter = new wxComboBox(
        this,
        wxID_ANY,
        wxT(""),
        wxDefaultPosition,
        wxDefaultSize,
        0,
        NULL,
        wxCB_DROPDOWN|wxCB_READONLY
    );

    wxBoxSizer* filterSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );
    filterSizer->Add(filterLabel);
    filterSizer->Add(m_filter);
    mainSizer->Add(filterSizer);

    // List of Messages section //The issue must be here somewhere...
    m_scrWin = new wxScrolledWindow(
        this,
        wxID_ANY
    );

    m_listSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    m_scrWin->SetSizer(m_listSizer);
    mainSizer->Add(m_scrWin, wxEXPAND); //m_scrWin should take the WHOLE of the interface.

    //example msg
    SMSMessage* exampleMessage = new SMSMessage(
        wxT("+44 07950 322 789"),
        wxT("2011-13-07 13:22"),
        wxT("Yo mate, what's up?")
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        AddSMSMessagePanel(*exampleMessage);
    }

    //wxSize minimum(300,500);

    m_scrWin->FitInside();                //Use fit inside to make the scrollwindow use the width of the items inside? without doing this I get no scrollbar at all...
    //m_scrWin->SetMinSize(minimum);
    //m_listSizer->SetMinSize(minimum);
    //m_scrWin->EnableScrolling(true, true);
    //m_scrWin->SetScrollRate(1,1);
    m_scrWin->SetScrollRate(5, 5);

    this->Layout();
    m_statusBar = this->CreateStatusBar( 1, wxST_SIZEGRIP, wxID_ANY );

    this->Centre( wxBOTH );

    // Connect Events
    this->Connect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( MainFrameBase::OnCloseFrame ) );
    this->Connect( menuFileOpen->GetId(), wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, wxCommandEventHandler( MainFrameBase::OnFileOpen ) );
    this->Connect( menuFileExit->GetId(), wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, wxCommandEventHandler( MainFrameBase::OnExitClick ) );
}

void MainFrameBase::AddSMSMessagePanel(const SMSMessage& message) {
    GUIMessageItem* gmi = new GUIMessageItem(m_scrWin, wxID_ANY, message); //object inherits from wxPanel
    m_listSizer->Add(gmi);
}
```

I'm sorry to bring such specific questions like this here, but I'm new to C++ and to wxWidgets and I've spent about 5 hours trying to solve this issue already and I don't
know what knowledge I lack.

This is a link to the complete source code: https://github.com/PhillipTaylor/SMSReader

Comment: Is there anything more I can do to encourage an answer on this question please?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Give it some more time, answering these question is not a high priority for most people. 2. Try to reproduce this problem with less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot of code to look at, and I do not pretend to understand what is going on.

You are writing and debugging a lot of code which could all be replaced by using wxGrid, as far as I can see.  Using wxGrid would make things a great deal simpler and all the tricky stuff is already tested and debugged for you.

Comment: Thank you. There was a missing function that I didn't include that did (now shown above). I also added a call to m_listSizer->Layout(); (not shown above) which didn't make any difference..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code generated by DialogBlocks. Should create the layout as you described.

```
void test::CreateControls()
{    
////@begin test content construction
    test* itemPanel1 = this;

    wxBoxSizer* itemBoxSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    itemPanel1->SetSizer(itemBoxSizer2);

    wxBoxSizer* itemBoxSizer3 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    itemBoxSizer2->Add(itemBoxSizer3, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT|wxLEFT|wxRIGHT|wxTOP, 5);

    wxStaticText* itemStaticText4 = new wxStaticText( itemPanel1, wxID_STATIC, _("Static text"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    itemBoxSizer3->Add(itemStaticText4, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL, 5);

    wxArrayString itemChoice5Strings;
    wxChoice* itemChoice5 = new wxChoice( itemPanel1, ID_CHOICE, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, itemChoice5Strings, 0 );
    itemBoxSizer3->Add(itemChoice5, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL, 5);

    wxArrayString itemSimpleHtmlListBox6Strings;
    wxSimpleHtmlListBox* itemSimpleHtmlListBox6 = new wxSimpleHtmlListBox( itemPanel1, ID_SIMPLEHTMLLISTBOX, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400, 300), itemSimpleHtmlListBox6Strings, wxHLB_DEFAULT_STYLE );
    itemBoxSizer2->Add(itemSimpleHtmlListBox6, 1, wxGROW|wxLEFT|wxRIGHT|wxBOTTOM, 5);

////@end test content construction
}
```